# Adding a Variable based on IF Statement Not Working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several variables that I then add based on the users input. It works with one exception. The user has an option to pay with cash or a credit/card. If they choose the credit card option a $.50 surcharge is added. The problem is I cannot get the surcharge to add to the amount total.

Here is my code (I've removed the other options and left one to reduce the code.):

```
$(function() {

    var surcharge = parseFloat("0"),
                dsT = parseFloat("0");

    $('input[type=radio][name=CAT_Custom_1657686]').on('ifChecked', function(event){
        if (this.value == 'I will pay with cash at purchase pickup') {
             var surcharge = parseFloat("0");
             amountTotal();
        } else {
             var surcharge = parseFloat(".50");
             amountTotal();
        }
    });


    $("#CAT_Custom_1657649").change(function (){
        var ds = parseFloat("6.00");
           dsQ = $(this).val(),
           dsT = ds * parseFloat(dsQ);
           amountTotal();
    });


    function amountTotal() {
        var myTotal = surcharge + dsT;
        $("#Amount").val(myTotal);
        console.log(myTotal);
    } 


    $('input').iCheck({
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square',
        radioClass: 'iradio_square',
        aria: true
    });

});
```

[Here is a fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/670ejobz/) to working code showing the problem.

As you will see I am using the iCheck to style the radio inputs. I don't believe it is causing the problem.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: the `var` in `var surcharge` inside your 'ifchecked' function masks the global surcharge variable

Comment: Lynda, go through this when you get time [You Don't Know JS - scope & closures](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/scope%20%26%20closures)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining the variable in the scope again.

Get rid of those `var` keywords when you are assigning the value to the variable.

This

`var surcharge = parseFloat("0");`

should be replaced by this

`surcharge = parseFloat("0");`

and the same for the other one.

Answer (score 1):

> Using `var` will create new instance of the variable hence it will not change the value of global variable. `var surcharge` will create new `local scope` for *surcharge*

Ty this:

```
if (this.value == 'I will pay with cash at purchase pickup') {
                     surcharge = parseFloat("0");
                     amountTotal();
                } else {
                     surcharge = parseFloat(".50");
                     amountTotal();
                }
```

[**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/670ejobz/2/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the scope of the variables `dsT` and `surcharge`.

A good solution will be to find their values in the `addTotal` method like

```js
$(function() {

  var surcharge = parseFloat("0"),
    dsT = parseFloat("0");

  $('input[type=radio][name=CAT_Custom_1657686]').on('ifChecked', amountTotal);


  $("#CAT_Custom_1657649").change(amountTotal);


  function amountTotal() {
    var ds = 6,
      dsQ = $("#CAT_Custom_1657649").val(),
      dsT = ds * parseFloat(dsQ),
      surcharge = $('input[type=radio][name=CAT_Custom_1657686]:checked').data('surchange');

    var myTotal = surcharge + dsT;
    $("#Amount").val(myTotal);
  }

  //iCHECK PLUGIN
  $('input').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square',
    radioClass: 'iradio_square',
    aria: true
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://icheck.fronteed.com/icheck.js"></script>
<link href="http://icheck.fronteed.com/skins/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<label for="CAT_Custom_1657649">Daily Special</label>
<select name="CAT_Custom_1657649" id="CAT_Custom_1657649" class="cat_dropdown">
  <option value="0" selected>0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<br>
<br>

<label>Payment</label>
<br>
<input name="CAT_Custom_1657686" id="CAT_Custom_1657686_0" value="I will pay with cash at purchase pickup" type="radio" data-surchange="0">&nbsp; I will pay with cash at purchase pickup
<br>
<input name="CAT_Custom_1657686" id="CAT_Custom_1657686_1" value="I will pay with credit/debit card immediately" type="radio" data-surchange="0.5">&nbsp; I will pay with credit/debit card immediately

<br>
<br>Amount:
<input type="text" name="Amount" id="Amount" class="purchase-amount" readonly />
```